# Skipping the locked rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am updating getting a first row of a table using select for UPDATE NOWAIT.
`SELECT * from table where rownum=1 for UPDATE NOWAIT;`
There are multiple instances of the same process working here. So next instance may get find table locked.
How can I skip the locked rows here ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple:

```
select * from table where rownum=1 for update skip locked;
```

I don't know how the rownum filter will work though, I think the second reader will get the first free record (not locked) but it could also mean that it will get no hits. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

The "where rownum = 1" part does not work as intended. It seems that the "for update skip locked" clause is evaluated after the where clause. So *first* you select the record you might potentially want and *then* you can skip those that are locked. 
Unfortunately I don't see how you can implement something like "give me the first one that is unlocked" with just one query.